# Magento Store view URL

Tags: magento2, multistore, url, store-view

We have Magento with **3 stores** with language **English and Arabic** for each. It is working fine without any issue. We are planning to change the URL of each website.

**Current URL**:

> http://example.com/kw_en/
>
> http://example.com/kw_ar/
>
> http://example.com/sa_en/
>
> http://example.com/sa_ar/

**Need to change the above URLs as below:**

> http://example.com/kw/en/
>
> http://example.com/kw/ar/
>
> http://example.com/sa/en/
>
> http://example.com/sa/ar/

Is there any we can do it?